# How to prove that bijective functions have surjective inverses

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove

> Since $f$ is bijective therefore it has an inverse and $f^{-1}$ is
>   bijective

But stuck on proving that $f^{-1}$ is surjective

Suppose $f: A \to B$ is a bijection, then a proof of $f^{-1}$ is surjective is offered in another post which says

> If $x \in A$ then $f(x) \in f(A) = B$ then $x \in f^{-1}(B)$.  If $y =
> > f^{-1}(B)$ then there exists a $f(y) \in B$ so that $f^{-1}(f(y)) = y
>  \in A$.  So $f^{-1}(B) = A$.

I have no idea what the proof is trying to do. Can someone construct a more lucid version of the proof or clarify what the proof is trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all $x\in A$ there is $y\in B$ such that $f(x)=y$; thus $f^{-1}(y)=x$. Therefore $f^{-1}$ is surjective.